# Final render not showing full node setup

Tags: compositing-nodes

I am learning how to use the node editing but have come up with a problem. I have followed the instructions that were give on a tutorial but I cannot get the effect to work there are 2 effects that I want to appear in the final render but only one appears. Here is a screen shot of my node set up. If anybody knows what i have done wrong could you please tell me . Thank you. If you need any more information please just let me know. If I am asking wrong questions or asking for the wrong information i am sorry but I am new to this site and am just learning how to use the site properly. *([larger image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAWOo.jpg))*

[image: compostion node set up]

Comment: I have tried attaching the compositor in different places to the star nodes and the nova nodes and i lose all effects. I have tried to place it at the end of the effects node frame as well but again I lose all effects, where it is placed now I can get the effect of the light in the star.

Comment: No worries Lindsey, we all try. Your questions are ok but can you please be as specific as possible when asking? For example, what tutorial? It makes it easier for us to see where you might have went wrong. Also, try to put all the information you think we need in the actual question and not in the comments. :)

Comment: If you haven't already, I would recommend reading the through the "Tips on asking Questions" (http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and the post on meta about what questions are off-topic: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic . The main thing to keep in mind when asking questions is "Can this be answered with solid facts?", if so, your question is probably valid. :)

Comment: Lindsey, based on the issue we spoke about in the chat, what you ask in the question and what you want are two different things. Please clarify it when you get the time, I also recommend that you rewatch the compositing part(s) of the tutorial.

Comment: I re-did the tutorial once again on 2.67b with no joy, then decided to do it on older version 2.62, to test, and everything worked fine. So I have reported it as a bug.

Answer (score 6):

Looking at your node setup, I think it is because you have the wrong socket plugged into the *Composite* node. It should be coming from the same *Add* node that the *Viewer* node is also plugged into. Maybe you were testing earlier and forgot to change it back?

Also, you can enable *Backdrop* while in the compositor to update your changes as you work, this can save you the time of rendering everytime you need to try a certain setup or see changes.

See [What is the difference between a Viewer and a Compositor node?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60/what-is-the-difference-between-a-viewer-and-a-compositor-node) for more information.

[image]

Comment: Thank you ikIsR I tried to plug the composite into the place that you suggested and I lost all of the effects again. Sorry for not mentioning the tutorial, it was http//cgcookie.com/blender/cgc-courses/creating-a-nova-explosion/ Sorry for not linking it but I don't know how to on a comment. Also when putting in a comment regarding the question I thought I had hit edit question. My aplogies

Comment: @Lindsey no worries. :) Can you attach the `.blend` to your question up above.

Comment: @ikIsR if you let me know how to attach blend file to a comment I will do so. cheers

Comment: @Lindsey you can use [PasteAll.org](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/). Just pack the blend file, upload it there and paste the link in the question so we can see it.

Comment: @iKIsR blend file uploaded but be warned uploading speed is slow so I don't know when you will be able to acces it. [http://PasteAll.org]

Comment: @Lindsey that 'link' is invalid.

Comment: [http://www.PasteAll.org/blend/supanova.blend]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9425/discussion-between-lindsey-and-iklsr)

Comment: @ikIsR thankyou i wil re-watch the tutorial and thank you for the help