# How to render nodes + background image?

Tags: rendering, node-editor, compositing-nodes, render-layers

I finished my work and I want to render everything. The object and the background.
I use the nodes to cast a shadow on the background image. I did this thanks to a tutorial on youtube. But the guy doesn't show how to save or how to render this final image made with the nodes.

Here are my nodes with the final image in the background and the result I'd like to get in my render:

[image]

Here is the result I get when I press the Render button:

[image]

As you can see, it only rendered my renderlayer, which contains the mesh plane and the strange rock and that's not what I want...

Comment: The node labeled **"composite''** is yous final output. It should be connected to the same mix node as the viewer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connect the last node in your tree of nodes to both [**Compositor**](http://www.blender.org/manual/composite_nodes/types/output/composite.html) node and [**Viewer**](http://www.blender.org/manual/composite_nodes/types/output/viewer.html) node, because the node which is connected to either **Compositor** or **Viewer** will be one acessible for preview in result.

Basically, **Viewer** allows you only to preview the result which you're working on, while **Compositor** will make this result to be actually rendered.

[image]

At the moment you have your original image connected to **Compositor** node which is why you get that not expected result. Also you have your composited image connected to **Viewer** node, and that's why you can preview eveything nicely.

Read more on difference between these nodes in [wiki](http://www.blender.org/manual/composite_nodes/types/output/index.html) or in this related question: [What is the difference between **Viewer** and a **Compositor** node](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60/what-is-the-difference-between-a-viewer-and-a-compositor-node).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Mr Zak's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43473/5705) you also need to change the Image Editor view to display the composite.  Currently you are only looking at the raw render result.  Change the dropdown menu at the bottom of the view from *Render Layers* to *Composite* to see the compositing result.

[image]

Comment: Can't believe that I could miss that. Thanks for adding!