# My composite won't render

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I'm modeling the Earth, and I did some stuff in the Compositing nodes. The stuff I did to the earth, won't render. I already have *Compositing* checkbox in the Render tab under Post processing scroll checked. I don't know what to do.

Here are my node things if that helps:

[image: screenshot of the node tree]

Comment: First you should render the scene as there isn't any data in the Render Layer. Then make sure to connect output of nodes into Composite node in order to render and Viewer node to preview it. See [difference between these nodes](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60/what-is-the-difference-between-a-viewer-and-a-compositor-node).

Comment: Yep, what Mr Zak said. Also, if you're just doing an F12 still render, the compositor output will go to the UV Editor, where you'll have to manually save the image to disk. This happens automatically if you're rendering out an animation.

Comment: Wait so what so which node to I connect to the composite? Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: To render final result which you created connect last node in the tree (MixRGB node set to Add operation in your case) to the output which is Composite node.  Viewer node can be connected too, though this is only for your convenience (to preview).